# Android fragment refresh on back press

Tags: java, android, fragment, refresh

I have an application that displays data from a database in a list view, when clicking an item in the list view it opens an activity and displays more data about that specific item, including the ability to delete it. when it deletes it, the first fragment is brought out of the back stack, however, the list view does not update to show the deletion, how can I make the fragment refresh it when its pull from the back stack?

the fragments activity has this in the onBackPressed

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() != 0) {
            fragmentManager.popBackStack();
        }
        else if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can override it's `onResume()` method and update the list there by calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` if you have some kind of a `ListAdapter` or something. Try that and see if it works.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26606527/android-refresh-a-fragment-list-from-its-parent-activity

Answer (score 3):

update your listview adaptor

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle   savedInstanceState) {
 super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
 if (listAdaptor != null){
   listAdaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
 }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, what do i do with this?

Answer (score 0):

Add this listner to your in your activity.

```
 getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(getListener());

  private FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener getListener() {
        FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener result = new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
            public void onBackStackChanged() {
                FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();

                if (manager != null) {
                    manager.findFragmentById(R.id.mall_fragment_container).onResume();
                }
            }
        };

        return result;
    }
```

it will call to fragment onresume when change in backstack. Do your job in onresume of your fragment. Note dont forgot to ad fragment to backstack.

Thanks