# Refresh a Fragment from mainactivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, searchview

I have an `Activity` with three tabs and three `Fragments`. First `Fragment` shows the list of song titles and the second tab displays the selected song. The details of the songs is coming from a database.
I am implementing `SearchView` feature so that whatever search text user enters, only those songs should be displayed in the index.

This is exactly like the way phone book work in our devices.

[image]

I'm not able to understand how to refresh the first `Fragment` when the search query changes.
I'm basically looking for the method that I can call to refresh the first `Fragment`.

Comment: are you using listview for the items to display?

Comment: this link may help you **[Android refresh a fragment list from its parent activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26606527/android-refresh-a-fragment-list-from-its-parent-activity)**

Comment: yes I'm using a custom list.

Comment: you can create your own interface and implement it in fragments where you can get callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got my answer here  [Android refresh a fragment list from its parent activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26606527/android-refresh-a-fragment-list-from-its-parent-activity) as suggested by @Prem. Works perfectly fine for me.

Its is achievable by making an interface

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public FragmentRefreshListener getFragmentRefreshListener() {
    return fragmentRefreshListener;
}

public void setFragmentRefreshListener(FragmentRefreshListener fragmentRefreshListener) {
    this.fragmentRefreshListener = fragmentRefreshListener;
}

private FragmentRefreshListener fragmentRefreshListener;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRefreshFragment);

    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(getFragmentRefreshListener()!=null){
                getFragmentRefreshListener().onRefresh();
            }
        }
    });


}


public interface FragmentRefreshListener{
    void onRefresh();
}}
```

**MyFragment.java**

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = null; // some view

    /// Your Code


    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).setFragmentRefreshListener(new MainActivity.FragmentRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {

            // Refresh Your Fragment
        }
    });


    return v;
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is the one way, you can easily do it. You just have to save the fragment instance. That's all.

```
    private class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private SparseArray<Fragment> array = new SparseArray<>();

    ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        array.setValueAt(position, myFragment);
        return myFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    public SparseArray<Fragment> getFragmentArray() {
        return array;
    }
}
```

Then from your activity, you can get all viewpager fragment easily from adapter instance.

```
MyFragment fragment = (MyFragment) adapter.getFragmentArray().get(0); // get first fragment and casting it to your origin fragment
```

Then create a method on that fragment. Call like below:

```
fragment.myFragmentMethod(String myData){}
```

Have a nice day!