# data parsed from activity to fragment dosent appear on first load

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I have the fragment in which I load recycler view and i load data for it from an activity which loads it from JSON. But when the first time the fragment opened it doesn't load the data, it loads only when the fragment is clicked again. Codes for My Activity and fragment are listed below.

**Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ActionBar actionbar;
TextView textview;
ActionBar.LayoutParams layoutparams;
public static final int NUMBER_OF_ADS = 2;

private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private AdLoader adLoader;
private List<Object> mTrollList = new ArrayList<>();
private List<UnifiedNativeAd> mNativeAds = new ArrayList<>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MobileAds.initialize(this, getString(R.string.admob_app_id));
    BottomNavigationView bottomnav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    BottomNavigationViewHelper.removeShiftMode(bottomnav);
    bottomnav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);

    mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);


    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container ,new VideoFragment()).commit();
    bottomnav.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_videos);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_new);
    bottomnav.setItemIconTintList(null);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // Update the RecyclerView item's list with menu items.
        addMenuItemsFromJson();
        // Update the RecyclerView item's list with native ads.
        loadNativeAds();

    }
}

private void insertAdsInMenuItems() {
    if (mNativeAds.size() <= 0) {
        return;
    }
    if(mTrollList.size()<1){
        return;
    }
    int offset = (mTrollList.size() / mNativeAds.size()) + 1;
    int index = 2;
    for (UnifiedNativeAd ad : mNativeAds) {
        mTrollList.add(index, ad);
        index = index + offset;
    }

}

private void loadNativeAds() {

    AdLoader.Builder builder = new AdLoader.Builder(Objects.requireNonNull(this), getString(R.string.ad_unit_id));
    adLoader = builder.forUnifiedNativeAd(
            new UnifiedNativeAd.OnUnifiedNativeAdLoadedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onUnifiedNativeAdLoaded(UnifiedNativeAd unifiedNativeAd) {
                    // A native ad loaded successfully, check if the ad loader has finished loading
                    // and if so, insert the ads into the list.
                    mNativeAds.add(unifiedNativeAd);
                    if (!adLoader.isLoading()) {
                        insertAdsInMenuItems();
                    }
                }
            }).withAdListener(
            new AdListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                    // A native ad failed to load, check if the ad loader has finished loading
                    // and if so, insert the ads into the list.
                    Log.e("MainActivity", "The previous native ad failed to load. Attempting to"
                            + " load another.");
                    if (!adLoader.isLoading()) {
                        insertAdsInMenuItems();
                    }
                }
            }).build();

    //Do something after 100ms
    adLoader.loadAds(new AdRequest.Builder().build(), NUMBER_OF_ADS);
}


public List<Object> getRecyclerViewItems() {
    return mTrollList;
}

private void addMenuItemsFromJson(){
    String url =getString(R.string.server_link);
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("server_response");
                        for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                            JSONObject ser =jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            String troll_image = ser.getString("troll_image");
                            String troll_caption =  ser.getString("troll_caption");
                            TrollItem trollItem = new TrollItem(troll_image,troll_caption);
                            mTrollList.add(trollItem);

                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }

    });

    mRequestQueue.add(request);
}



public void setActionBarTitle(String title) {
    actionbar = getSupportActionBar();

    textview = new TextView(getApplicationContext());

    layoutparams = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    textview.setLayoutParams(layoutparams);

    textview.setText(title);

    textview.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

    textview.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    textview.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

    textview.setTextSize(20);

    actionbar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);

    actionbar.setCustomView(textview);
}

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_videos:
                Fragment videoFragment = new VideoFragment();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        videoFragment).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.navigation_photos:
                Fragment photoFragment = new PhotoFragment();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        photoFragment).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.navigation_dvd:
                Fragment dvdFragment = new DvdFragment();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        dvdFragment).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.navigation_news:
                Fragment newsFargment = new NewsFragment();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        newsFargment).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.navigation_troll:
                Log.e("datafirst", String.valueOf(mTrollList.size()+"activity"));
                Fragment trollFragment = new TrollFragment();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        trollFragment).commit();
                break;
        }return true;}};}
```

**Fragment**

```
public class TrollFragment extends Fragment {
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private TrollAdapter mTrollAdapter;
private List<Object> mTrollList;



public TrollFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // retain this fragment
    setRetainInstance(true);
    MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
    mTrollList = activity.getRecyclerViewItems();

    Log.e("datafirst", String.valueOf(mTrollList.size()));
   getContext();

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    ((MainActivity) Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity())).setActionBarTitle("Trolls");
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_troll, container, false);
    mRecyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_troll);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);


    SnapHelper snapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
    snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(mRecyclerView);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
    mTrollAdapter = new TrollAdapter(getActivity(), mTrollList);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mTrollAdapter);

    return rootView;
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In one sentence problem is: calling `synchronous` code which is
>   actually `asynchronous`.

**Explanation**:

You load `Fragment` inside `onCreate` and you also make a network call to fetch data. `Synchronous` ea. `Fragment` replacement is executed immediately instead of `asynchronous` ea. network call, which can take from hundreds of miliseconds to seconds.

When your `Fragment` calls `mTrollList = activity.getRecyclerViewItems();` there is no data, `List` is empty because data is not returned from the network. That is why you have data when `Fragment` is refreshed because meantime `List` got its data.

**Solution**:

There is couple solutions to this problem. One of the most known is to use `callbacks`. Create na `interface` which you will `implement` (or in another words subscribe), inside your `Fragment` and pass (or notify subscribers) the data from `Activity` to that `Fragment` once data is returned from network. So

Create an `interface` in your `MainActivity`:

```
 public interface OnDataFetched {
    void fetchSuccess(List<Object> mTrollList);
}
```

After that create filed in `MainActivity`:

```
private OnDataFetched onDataFetched;
```

And then create a `public` method also inside `MainActivity`:

```
 public void subscribe(OnDataFetched onDataFetched) {
    this.onDataFetched = onDataFetched;
}
```

Now inside Volley `onResponse`, outside or after `for` loop notify subscribers:

```
if (onDataFetched != null) {
    onDataFetched.fetchSuccess(mTrollList);
}
```

Now go to your `Fragment` and `implement` this interface and `override` method `fetchSuccess`:

```
public class TrollFragment extends Fragment implements OnDataFetched
...

@Override
public void fetchSuccess(List<Object> mTrollList) {

}
```

Remove this code from `Fragment onCreate` method:

```
MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
mTrollList = activity.getRecyclerViewItems();
```

Instead of this call:

```
((MainActivity)getActivity()).subscribe(this);
```

And after that you can move this code inside overrided `fetchSuccess` method:

```
@Override
public void fetchSuccess(List<Object> mTrollList) {
  mTrollAdapter = new TrollAdapter(getActivity(), mTrollList);
  mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mTrollAdapter);
}
```

And that would be it.

Comment: after applying your solution it still doesn't appear sometimes.

Comment: @maranamass can you update the question with your changes you have made?

Comment: The data appers sometimes. When it dosent apper iam getting this error from log 'com.malfilm.app.filmappnew E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout'.

Comment: @maranamass debug your Volley `response` check do you get data correctly. Check root of your adapters layout is `height` set on `wrap_content`

Comment: This is my new updated code    https://pastebin.com/pPCphNMM  sometimes the data in recycler view are apperain but sometimes it shows no adapter attached.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of calling getRecyclerViewItems from your fragment. Pass data to your fragment using

```
fragmentObject.setArguments(bundle);
```

And then inside your fragments use

```
getArguments();
```

To get the data.

This way you’ll get your data on the first run too and your fragment’s dependency from MainActivity will be removed (the way the fragments are meant to be used)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply Use Interface to get the result. You just need it call interface method when list updates in MainActivity.
You can refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26606993/6180837) to implement interface similar to your case.

Comment: can you please elaborate iam a new to android development.